# Post Request Failing Randomly: Rails String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a recordings table with a date column that is of the type string. The model validates the existence of date. When I try to POST to the route that creates new recordings I get a variety of strange responses...including successes. All of the below are consistently returning these responses, so I don't think it's a matter of when or what order I put them in. I also am confident that params include "date" key and are associated with the below strings since the server is telling me the params its receiving.

"1234"  or "53" returns

```
ArgumentError (argument out of range)
```

"123", "12", "Feb", "feb" returns

```
work
```

*Not really relevant since I can't repeat it with longer strings*

*"1", any two letters(whether capital or not), "Men" or "men" return
    {
    "errors":[
    "Date can't be blank"
    ]
    }
Feb/feb works but Men/men gets the error concerning the date not existing.*

I have dropped the databases. I've remigrated them. I've then deployed via Cap again. The weirdness remains, but it does not exist at all on my local server. I am at a loss.

Edit:

an example of a failing 500 argument out of range

```
I, [2014-02-25T04:39:49.362396 #8892]  INFO -- : Processing by API::V1::PatientsController#show as JSON
I, [2014-02-25T04:39:49.362615 #8892]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"token"=>"VgfDqgsX1wt9zt-hEXnU", "id"=>"0"}
I, [2014-02-25T04:39:49.494759 #8892]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 17.2ms)
I, [2014-02-25T04:40:06.813557 #8895]  INFO -- : Started POST "/api/v1/recording?token=kVqFKuj3kpX7aX3UUQft&date=02-24-2014_19-39-03_PST&position=left&image_file=whatever.img&sound_file=sound.mp3&PID=ab" for 74.51.144.67 at 2014-02-25 04:40:06 +0000
I, [2014-02-25T04:40:06.815150 #8895]  INFO -- : Processing by API::V1::RecordingsController#create as JSON
I, [2014-02-25T04:40:06.815498 #8895]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"token"=>"kVqFKuj3kpX7aX3UUQft", "date"=>"02-24-2014_19-39-03_PST", "position"=>"left", "image_file"=>"whatever.img", "sound_file"=>"sound.mp3", "PID"=>"ab"}
I, [2014-02-25T04:40:06.821460 #8895]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
F, [2014-02-25T04:40:06.823280 #8895] FATAL -- :
ArgumentError (argument out of range):
  app/controllers/api/v1/recordings_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

an example of a success

```
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:10.637765 #8892]  INFO -- : Processing by API::V1::PatientsController#show as JSON
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:10.637979 #8892]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"token"=>"VgfDqgsX1wt9zt-hEXnU", "id"=>"0"}
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:10.778589 #8892]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:26.323157 #8895]  INFO -- : Started POST "/api/v1/recording?token=kVqFKuj3kpX7aX3UUQft&date=nov_10th_2013-12:00&position=left&image_file=whatever.img&sound_file=sound.mp3&PID=ab" for 74.51.144.67 at 2014-02-25 04:44:26 +0000
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:26.324878 #8895]  INFO -- : Processing by API::V1::RecordingsController#create as JSON
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:26.325112 #8895]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"token"=>"kVqFKuj3kpX7aX3UUQft", "date"=>"nov_10th_2013-12:00", "position"=>"left", "image_file"=>"whatever.img", "sound_file"=>"sound.mp3", "PID"=>"ab"}
I, [2014-02-25T04:44:26.390239 #8895]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 36.8ms)
```

Edit

Controller code + Complete Walk Through of Request

```
  def restrict_access_by_token
    @current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
    if @current_user.blank?
      render json: {content: 'No user with that authentication token exists.',}, status: 401
    end
    @current_user = @current_user[0]
  end

  def permit_params
    params.permit(:date, :position, :sound_file, :image_file, :audo_data_points, :patient_id, :token, :format, :PID)
  end


 def create 
    @recording = Recording.new(permit_params.delete_if { |k,v| ["token", "format", "PID"].include? k })
    if @recording.save
      @recording.update_attribute("user_id", @current_user.id)
      possible_patients = Patient.where("user_id = ?", @current_user.id)
      patient = possible_patients.find{|patient| (patient.identifier.decrypt ENV['STRONGBOX']) == params["PID"]}
      if patient.blank?
        render json: {error: "Need a PID param to associate recording with."}, status: 401
      else
        patient.recordings << @recording
        @recording = decrypt_hash(@recording)
        render json: {recording_id: @recording["id"]}, status: 200
      end
    else
      render json: {errors: @recording.errors.full_messages}, status: 401
    end
  end

  def decrypt_hash(object)
    hash = object.attributes
    if object.class == Patient
      return decrypt(object, hash, ["identifier", "first_name", "last_name", "dob"])
    elsif object.class == Note
      return decrypt(object, hash, ["content"])
    elsif object.class == Recording
      return decrypt(object, hash, ["sound_file", "image_file"])
    end
  end

  def decrypt(object, hash, encrypted_files)
    hash.map do |k, v|
      if encrypted_files.include? k
        hash[k] = object.send(k).decrypt ENV["STRONGBOX"]
      end
    end
    delete_extra_encryption_fields(hash)
  end

  def delete_extra_encryption_fields(hash)
    delete_array = []
    hash.each do |k, v|
      delete_array << k + "_key"
      delete_array << k + "_iv"
    end
    hash.delete_if { |k,v| delete_array.include? k }
  end
```

Comment: Can we see the actual code and logs of what's going on? The description is not at all clear.

Comment: In addition, why is the type for your data a string and not a date?

Comment: what params you are passing on what route? Are those params are handled.

Comment: Added them; sorry. As for why a string and not a date because we were having issues getting the Objective C date object to not run into this exact issue and I thought it might be related to the AR datetime not being compatible with Objective C date objects. Clearly not.

Comment: can we see the controller code? That's not any sort of standard date formatting, and it appears that Rails is choking on it.

Comment: That's why I thought switching over to a string would be effective; Rails shouldn't care at all about the date format because it's a string being put into a string field. The only indicator it's a date is the field name.

Comment: Are you only validating the presence of the date field? It seems like (argument out of range) comes from parsing the time. @sevenseacat

Comment: I added the complete code path of the POST request; there is decryption going on, but .attributes is the only thing that should be impacting the date field since it isn't one of the encrypted fields.

Comment: Only thing in my model referencing the date field is the validation check.